# How can I ensure that an array of objects contains only one of a particular key with Joi?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I have something like:

```js
  let moduleId

  moduleRackOutputs.forEach((output) => {
    if (!moduleId) {
      moduleId = output.moduleId
    } else if (output.moduleId !== moduleId) {
      errors.add([
        'The drawing contains more than one module type. Multiple module types are not yet supported by the PVsyst RPA.'
      ])
    }
  })
```

I want to convert this to a `Joi` schema. How would I accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished as follows:

```
Joi.array()
    .items(
        Joi.object().keys({
            moduleId: Joi.string().required(),
            framingType: Joi.string().required()
        })
    )
    .unique((a, b) => a.moduleId !== b.moduleId)
    .message({
        'array.unique': 'The drawing contains more than one module type...'
    })
    .unique((a, b) => a.framingType !== b.framingType)
    .message({
        'array.unique': 'The drawing contains more than one framing type...'
    })
```

Comment: How can I extend it if it's `rack.framingType` instead of `moduleId`?

Comment: You'd replace `moduleId` in the schema and unique check with `framingType`.

Comment: Mind throwing up an example in your answer?

Comment: To be clear - I Want both.. moduleId and `rack.framingType`

Comment: Items should not have different `moduleId`'s or `rack.framingType`s

Comment: I've added `framingType` to the schema.

Comment: Any way to have different messages depending on which one is being violated?

Comment: Yep, edited again

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Joi.array method and pass it only one key you would like the object to have

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
    arrayObjects: Joi.array().items(
      Joi
      .object()
      .keys(
        {keyElement:Joi.string()}
        )
     )
});
```

Comment: I want one and only one element that has a `moduleId`