# How can I have multiple unique checks with a Joi schema validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I have data:

```
const mockScenario1 = {
  drawingNode: {
    moduleRackOutputs: [
      {
        moduleId: 'module1',
        tilt: 'tilt1',
        rack: {
          framingType: 'framing1'
        }
      },
      {
        moduleId: 'module2',
        tilt: 'tilt1',
        rack: {
          framingType: 'framing1'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to ensure that:

- If there are different `moduleId` values, I want: `Only one module allowed`
- If there are different `rack.framingType` values, I want: `Only one framing type allowed`

I have this sort of started with:

```
Joi.object({
  drawingNode: Joi.object({
    moduleRackOutputs: Joi.array()
      .items(
        Joi.object().keys({
          moduleId: Joi.string().required(),
          tilt: Joi.string().required(),
          rack: Joi.object({
            framingType: Joi.string().required()
          })
        })
      )
      .unique((a, b) => a.moduleId !== b.moduleId)
      .messages({
        'array.unique':
          'The drawing contains more than one module type. Multiple module types are not yet supported by the PVsyst RPA.'
      })
  })
})
```

Which works for the module, but not the framingType. Seems I can't use multiple `unique`?

I'd love any help or pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ensure that an array of objects contains only one of a particular key with Joi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623285/how-can-i-ensure-that-an-array-of-objects-contains-only-one-of-a-particular-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Solution. I hope it would help.

```
Joi.object({
   drawingNode: Joi.object({
     moduleRackOutputs: 
     Joi.array().unique('moduleId').unique('rack.framingType')
     .messages({
        'array.unique':
        'The drawing contains more than one module type. Multiple module types are not yet supported by the PVsyst RPA.'
        })
      })
     })
```

**OR**

```
Joi.object({
  drawingNode: Joi.object({
  moduleRackOutputs: Joi.array()
  .items(
    Joi.object().keys({
      moduleId: Joi.string().required(),
      tilt: Joi.string().required(),
      rack: Joi.object({
        framingType: Joi.string().required()
      })
    })
  )
  .unique((a, b) => a.moduleId === b.moduleId || a.rack.framingType === b.rack.framingType)
  .messages({
    'array.unique':
      'The drawing contains more than one module type. Multiple module types are not yet supported by the PVsyst RPA.'
   })
 })
})
```